# Handling multiple UserControls

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik

I have a webpage Containing UserControl repeated 2 times with same functionality. I want to disable the textbox in first UserControl but it is getting disabled in 2nd UserControl.

How to check this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function confirmCallBackFn(arg)
{
    if (arg == true)
    {
        $find('<%= txtOne.ClientID %>').disable();
    }
}
```

Comment: Both controls have ID txtOne?

Comment: Yes because it is contained in a Usercontrol

Comment: Then reference it by its parent control. ParentControl.UserControl.ID

Comment: Any sample code? How can I do that at client side of it?

Comment: Not really without seeing your page. Best I can do in one sentence is look at your rendered HTML and see what the control is named and reference it directly by that ID. This could break if you add different controls, but it's the best I can do with the information I have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Method 1 - If the event is triggered by a control in the parent form**

In the user control, you can define a property that returns the ID of the TextBox:

```
public string TextBoxID
{
    get { return txtOne.ClientID; }
}
```

If your form contains two instances of the user control, `ctrl1` and `ctrl2`, you can target a specific one like this:

```
document.getElementById('<%= ctrl1.TextBoxID %>').disabled = true;
```

Note: In the user control, make sure that you don't use `ClientIDMode="Static"` for the inner controls.

**Method 2 - If the event is triggered by an inner control of the user control**

If your user control contains the following markup:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="chk1" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtOne" runat="server" />
```

you can add Javascript event handlers to the CheckBox in the `Page_Load` method of the user control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string js = string.Format("txtBoxID = '{0}';", txtOne.ClientID);
    chk1.Attributes.Add("onmousedown", js);
    chk1.Attributes.Add("onkeydown", js);
}
```

These event handlers set the value for a `txtBoxID` variable that you can define and use in your Javascript block:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var txtBoxID;

    function confirmCallBackFn(arg) {
        if (arg == true) {
            document.getElementById(txtBoxID).disabled = true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

This method assumes that there is no postback during the process. If a postback occurs, we may have to modify that method and register a script in the event handler in code-behind.

Comment: Where and how I can create ctrl1 and ctrl2. Could you please throw some light on this.

Comment: `ctrl1` and `ctrl2` would be the ID of each instance of the user control in your form.

Comment: There is a tricky question from my side. I am adding confirmCallBackFn in the child control and the name of the usercontrols are accessible from its parent control. How can I access names of the usercontrols ctrl1 and ctrl2 because you are inside on usercontrol. On click of confirm from child control, i need to get ctrl1 or ctrl2.

Comment: Yes, this is trickier. Is the event triggered by a control inside the same user control instance as the text box that you want to disable? And can you pass other arguments to `confirmCallBackFn`?

Comment: Yes the event is triggered by a control inside the same user control instance as the textbox that I want to disable. But how can an argument work in radconfirm window of Telerik.

Comment: I added another suggestion to my answer.

Comment: I am calling confirmCallBackfn from uncheck of checkbox(RadControl). How can I call confirmCallBackfn as well as onclick at the same time when unchecking the checkbox control.

Comment: And  I am calling the "confirmCallBackfn" from radWindowManager.RadConfirm and I cannot define this checkbox in page  load with different function name called "onclick"

Comment: One more update to my answer, using `onmousedown` and `onkeydown` instead of `onclick`. Maybe that can help you.

Comment: radWindowManager.RadConfirm("Are you sure you want to clear controls?", "confirmCallBackFn", 300, 100, null, ""); This is where I am calling radConfirm and confirmCallBackFn is mentioned in the question in Javascript. Am I missing  something. Can you come in chat?

Comment: How the sequence of events will be firing?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123050/discussion-between-cpk-2011-and-connorsfan).

Comment: Try my suggested "Method 2" (as it is now) and tell me if it works. The `mousedown` or `keydown` event will define the value of `txtBoxID`, which will then be used by `confirmCallBackFn`.